# How do I change the Apple ID on iPhoto?

Tags: macbook-pro, photos.app, apple-id

I gave my Macbook Pro to my partner, after reinstalling OSx on the laptop. My info was deleted by me before reinstalling the OS, but my Apple ID still shows up in iPhoto.

Comment: did you purchase it ?

Comment: Where in iPhoto does your ID still show up? If it is difficult to describe, could you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Open App store and click on sign out.

Now sign in with new apple id.

Be aware that the iPhoto belongs to your apple id.

The new apple id will not work with updates to iPhoto without paying for it.